# UIImage unable to load image from Brand Assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am using `LaunchImage` source from my app Assets that called :

```
Brand Assets
```

In this asset i have this files:

```
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-667h@2x.png
Default-736h@3x.png
Default@2x.png
```

I want to load one of this images to `UIImage` with:

```
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
```

And the `bg` is always nil, Any idea why? What i do wrong?

Comment: UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Brand Assets"]

Comment: @ARMV i try to use : `UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h.png"];` , it's still return nil

Comment: You should use assest name like @kholl wrote- UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Brand Assets"];

Comment: Could you upload the directory image like this so we can see where is the problem

Comment: I use Assets.xcassests for saving images and Without renaming them like you. I use [at]2x and [at]3x extensions and then create the images without the @ or .png or .jpg extension. You can try the same